# Haskell + counting substring

Tags: haskell, substring

I am very close to getting this but I still got stuck :/

```
txt :: String
txt = "[1] and [2] both feature characters who will do whatever it takes to " ++
  "get to their goal, and in the end the thing they want the most ends " ++
  "up destroying them.  In case of [3] this is a whale..."
references :: String -> Int

split :: String -> [String]
split str = words str

find :: [String] -> [String]
find xs = [ x | x <- xs, x == "["++"1"++"]" ]                           
references x = length (find (split x ))
```

I need to find the times `[n]` occurs in a string where `n` is an number `0` to whatever.

In the example above `n = 3`.

I cannot seem to write a predicate to catch all numbers represented as a string enclosed by brackets `"[1]"` or `"[3]"`.
(I hard coded 1 in my code here)

Comment: Although the other question doesn't show effort, it contains an excellent answer that pretty much explains everything. By the way, is there currently a Haskell course going on, or why do both you and @Chris need that particular code?

Comment: Yes, Comparative Programming Languages course at UC Santa Cruz. Also I would have loved to get help with my solution as it is different and I don't think we are supposed to use packages..oh well

Comment: @ajanakos thanks for being honest! While I have no problem with you asking questions (maybe not the same over and over again - use the search ;) ) - wouldn't it be better if you would all come together and learn in real life? I know I am getting old but in my days this was where it made *click* for most students (that or the tutorials on campus)

Comment: @Carsten Yes...heading to lab section tomorrow haha :)

Comment: Yeah I guess it's not easy when you struggle with the syntax and the concepts and IMO the Haskell community on this side does a great job in helping students out but the format here is not a good fit for tutor situations where you would want an iterative approach instead of the full answer up front - that's why I always learned a lot more in 3-4 person study groups - especially if there was no "know-all" around

Comment: @ajanakos: The other answer by leftroundabout isn't using packages, since `Data.Char.isNumber` is part of base. However, you can write `isNumber :: Char -> Bool` yourself, it's a small, valuable exercise. By the way, if your text only contains `[` and `]` for references, you don't even have to parse numbers…

Comment: True. Thanks for all the help!